# can't open selenium failed test on jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I was wondering if someone can help me with this issue that I am facing when I click on failed test browser screenshot in jenkins to see the failed image I got 404 page not found.

I had jenkins setup in linux machine and I am using 4 vm's grid which is work before in another machine the only thing I did I reinstall jenkins in new machine no changes has been done on the testlistener.

Hope that anyone can direct me to the right track.

[image]